# Combine structures in the same session - PyMOL

Tags: structural-biology, pymol

I'm a student currently looking at antibody responses against a viral target protein of interest.

I have my own, annotated PyMOL session of my protein and I also have .pdbs of crystallised antibody structures that bind to this protein and rougly know whereabouts it binds. I would like to know if it is possible to combine these two structures into a single session to observe or at least overlay the two structures together. Many thanks!

Comment: Is the question "Can I overlay/combine two structured in a single PyMOL session?"? (took me moment to figure what is actually the question, so I wanted to suggest how to make the question clearer).

Comment: Could you please describe what you did so far to solve the Problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the PyMOL session.
2. Use the `load` command to load your PDB file(s): `load file.pdb`.
3. Use the `align` or `super` commands to overlay structures, e.g. `align prot1, prot2`.